Latex code for tabular method of convolution
I'd like to write LaTeX code for the following table:


https://www.google.com/search?q=convolution+tabular+method&sca_esv=35ffd0becc4189bf&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE966DE966&sxsrf=ADLYWILEYXSyJlYWuOxAUZ1mXNhSMhAFNQ%3A1735479975457&ei=p1JxZ83AG8TH4-EPg4P2-Qg&oq=convolution+in+tabular+form+&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiHGNvbnZvbHV0aW9uIGluIHRhYnVsYXIgZm9ybSAqAggCMgQQIxgnMgQQIxgnMggQABiABBiiBDIIEAAYgAQYogQyCBAAGIAEGKIEMggQABiABBiiBDIIEAAYgAQYogRIpBlQ8wVY8wVwAXgBkAEAmAG6AaABugGqAQMwLjG4AQHIAQD4AQGYAgKgAskBwgIHECMYsAMYJ8ICChAAGLADGNYEGEeYAwCIBgGQBgSSBwMxLjGgB6wH&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Welcome to TeX.SE! Would you mind trying to construct a basic table of your own, and then ask us when you run into difficulty? For example, check out the package nicematrix. Best!

Welcome. // Here’s a more compact presentation of the tables content: y[n] = x1[n] * x2[n] … It’s a one-liner in math mode …

Here's a quick and easy solution using the tabularray package:

Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\(
\begin{tblr}{
    hline{2} = {0.4pt}, vline{2} = {0.4pt}, column{1-Z}={c, m}
    }
    \diagbox[innerleftsep=0.1cm, width=5em]{x_2[n]}{x_1[n]} & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
    3 & -3 & 6 & 0 & 3 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -1
\end{tblr}
\)

\end{document}

I'm in a hurry at the moment, so I apologize for the semi-finished solution. I'll look into the coloring of the table as well as proper alignment of the cells when I have time to optimize the code. I'll update the answer if I figure out the improvements!
Update
I'm home now, and trying to emulate the example as closely as possible and taking up Mico's suggestion with regards to alignment, this is what I could come up with:

Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\usepackage{xcolor} % For defining custom colors
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94} % For the lines
\definecolor{grannysmithapple}{rgb}{0.66, 0.89, 0.63} % For 1st row and column
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66} % For rows 2-Last(Z)
% All custom colors were found here: https://latexcolor.com/

\begin{document}

\(
\begin{tblr}{
    hline{2} = {0.75pt, babyblue}, vline{2} = {0.75pt, babyblue}, % linecolors
    colspec = {Q[r, 1cm]Q[r, 5mm]Q[r, 5mm]Q[r, 5mm]Q[r, 5mm]}, % Alignment and column width
    row{2-Z} = {fg = airforceblue}, column{1} = {fg = grannysmithapple}, row{1} = {fg = grannysmithapple} % Coloring of text in rows and columns
    }
    \diagbox[linecolor = babyblue, linewidth = 0.75pt, innerwidth=1cm, trim=r]{\hspace{-0.22cm}x_2[n]}{x_1[n]} & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
    3 & -3 & 6 & 0 & 3 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -1
\end{tblr}
\)

\end{document}

I found a list of LaTeX colors through which I tried to match your used color schemes.

Can you right-align the numbers in the four data columns, and give the four data columns equal width? These would appear to be two of the OP's formatting objectives.

Done now, along with other small improvements such as the size and alignment of the diagbox as well as line width and coloring.

The following implements your table, but it doesn't use the diagonally split cell for the header (because I don't like the looks of it), if you absolutely have to have this, you can use diagbox to achieve this.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ameya_line_seq
\NewDocumentCommand\ConvuTable{O{S} mm}
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_ameya_line_seq {#2}
    \begin{tabular}{#1|*{\seq_count:N \l_ameya_line_seq}{#1}}
      & \multicolumn{\seq_count:N \l_ameya_line_seq}{c}{$x\sb{1}[n]$} \\
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x\sb{2}[n]$}
      \use:e { \seq_map_tokens:Nn \l_ameya_line_seq { & \fp_eval:n } } \\
      \hline
      \use:e { \clist_map_function:nN {#3} \__ameya_convu_line:n }
    \end{tabular}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__ameya_convu_line:n #1
  {
    \fp_eval:n { #1 }
    \seq_map_tokens:Nn \l_ameya_line_seq { \__ameya_convu_cell:nn {#1} }
    \exp_not:N \\
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__ameya_convu_cell:nn #1#2
  {
    & \fp_eval:n { #1 * #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ConvuTable{-1, 2, 0, 1}{3, 1, 0, -1}
\end{document}



Here is another idea to present the information which avoids the slash and uses only standard commands.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
&    $\overbrace{\begin{array}{*{4}{wr{5mm}}} -1 & 2 & 0 & 1     \end{array}}^{\mbox{\normalsize $x_2[n]$}}$
\\
$x_1[n] \left\{ \begin{array}{r} 3 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{array} \right. $ \hspace*{-5mm}&
$\begin{array}{|*{4}{wr{5mm}}}
\hline  -3 & 6 & 0 & 3\\
 -1 & 2  & 0 &  1 \\
  0 & 0  & 0 &  0 \\
  1 & -2 & 0 & -1
\end{array}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}



The typographic quality of that table is really poor. The slash is to be avoided as it doesn't really make clear what the entries refer to.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  *{5}{S[table-format=-1.0]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
{$x_2[n]$} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$x_1[n]$} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
   & -1 &  2 & 0 &  1 \\
\midrule
 3 & -3 &  6 & 0 &  3 \\
 1 & -1 &  2 & 0 &  1 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & 0 &  0 \\
-1 &  1 & -2 & 0 & -1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



With tabularray ans spreadtab.
Like a spreadsheet, we copy the formula to the right and below with
        & -1  &   2   &   0   &   1\\  
   3    & \STcopy{>,v}{!a3*b!2}&&&\\

the ! replaces $ of spreadsheet.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec   ={*{5}{S[table-format=-1.0]}},
        cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c,guard,mode=math},% or {{{$x_1[n]$}}}
        cell{1}{1}={c,guard,mode=math},
        hline{1,Z}= {1pt},
        hline{2}  = {2-Z}{0.25pt},
        hline{3}  = {0.5pt},
}
x_2[n]&x_1[n]&&&\\
    & -1  &   2   &   0   &   1\\  
3     & -3  &   6   &   0   &   3\\
1     & -1  &   2   &   0   &   1\\
0     &  0  &   0   &   0   &   0\\
-1    &  1  &  -2   &   0   &  -1\\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip
\begin{spreadtab}{{tblr}{
    colspec   ={*{5}{S[table-format=-1.0]}},
    cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c,guard,mode=math},% or {{{$x_1[n]$}}}
    cell{1}{1}={c,guard,mode=math},
    hline{1,Z}= {1pt},
    hline{2}  = {2-Z}{0.25pt},
    hline{3}  = {0.5pt},
}}
@x_2[n]&@x_1[n]&&&\\
        & -1  &   2   &   0   &   1\\  
3    & \STcopy{>}{!a3*b2}&&&\\
1    & \STcopy{>}{!a4*b2}&&&\\
0    & \STcopy{>}{!a5*b2}&&&\\
-1    & \STcopy{>}{!a6*b2}&&&\\
\end{spreadtab}

\bigskip
\begin{spreadtab}{{tblr}{
    colspec   ={*{5}{S[table-format=-1.0]}},
    cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c,guard,mode=math},% or {{{$x_1[n]$}}}
    cell{1}{1}={c,guard,mode=math},
    hline{1,Z}= {1pt},
    hline{2}  = {2-Z}{0.25pt},
    hline{3}  = {0.5pt},
}}
@x_2[n]&@x_1[n]&&&\\
        & -1  &   2   &   0   &   1\\  
3    & \STcopy{>,v}{!a3*b!2}&&&\\
1    &                      &&&\\
0    &                      &&&\\
-1    &                      &&&\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}



If you actually want to construct your table with such design (maybe not a good idea: see other answers), here is a way with nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{w{c}{1.4cm}|cccc}
\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{24pt}
\diagbox{x_2[n]}{x_1[n]} & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\Hline
3 & -3 & 6 & 0 & 3 \\
1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -1
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}


